# Join two tables based on matched items in R

Tags: r

I've created a data frame to store the information for 100 texts.
And for each text, there are 10 rows.
So there are total 1000 rows for this data frame. 
E.g.,

```
  text name        text id

----------------------------------

1.  A                1      
2.  A                2
3.  A                3
...
10. A                10  
11. B                1    
12. B                2
...
20. B                10
...
```

And I have metadata for these texts in an excel spreadsheet, but I only have one row for each text. So, there are 100 rows in this dataset. 
It looks like this:

```
File Name     Author    Gender   Age
---------------------------------------
 A            Adam       male    48
 B            Brown      male    30
 C            Cindy      female  30
 D            Donaldd    female  20
```

Now, I want to create a new data frame so that I can join the metadata (say Gender) to every texts in the first data frame. 
Anyone has any idea to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take full power of formatting capabilities of stackoverflow and perhaps read up on how to [make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm confused about formatting in stackoverflow. Thanks for providing the link, it really helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching the value of the information for each text in the metadata (DF_2) to the first data frame (DF_1)

```
DF_1$Gender <- with(DF_2, Gender[match(DF_1$`text name`, DF_2$`File Name`)])
```

This should produce:

```
text name        text id     Gender

----------------------------------

1.  A                1      male
2.  A                2      male
3.  A                3      male   
...
10. A                10     male  
11. B                1      male    
12. B                2      male
...
20. B                10     male
...
```